# Notification doesn't show all action buttons

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm trying to create a simple notification for a music player that has 3 buttons, Pause, Previous and Next. My code only shows one of them which is Next. Any suggestions where I did a mistake? [image: It only shows one action button]

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Intent playNextIntent = new Intent(this, BroadcastReceiver.class);
    playNextIntent.setAction("NEXT_ACTION");
    PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, playNextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(this, BroadcastReceiver.class);
    pauseIntent.setAction("PAUSE_ACTION");
    PendingIntent pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, pauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent playPreviousIntent = new Intent(this, BroadcastReceiver.class);
    playPreviousIntent.setAction("PREVIOUS_ACTION");
    PendingIntent prevPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, playPreviousIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "D")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background) //notification icon
            .setContentTitle("Simple Music Player")
            .setContentText("Currently playing: " + mediaPlayerHolder.getSongsList().get(songIterator).getSongName())
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setWhen(0)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC) 
            .setOngoing(true) //user can't remove notification
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_previous, "Previous", prevPendingIntent) // #0
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "Pause", pausePendingIntent)  // #1
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "Next", nextPendingIntent)     // #2
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent); //on click go to app intent
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build()); //show notification
```

Comment: There's something weird going on with the notification in general, why is the `contentText` displayed twice? Have you tried it on a stock android emulator? Also you're setting a `BigTextStyle` but you're not actually setting a `BigText`, but I doubt that would cause any issues.

Comment: I forgot to delete .setStyle before I posted, without it the issue is still there but contentText is not displayed twice at least.

Comment: I would still suggest running it on a stock android emulator to make sure the issue is actually in your code and not in the launcher you have on your phone. Your launcher implements the `BigTextStyle` wrong so it may also have a bug with multiple actions.

Comment: You were right, on emulator and other version of android everything shows like expected, thanks.

Comment: Great! I've posted it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. If you run your code in an emulator on stock android the actions show up as expected.

On Android displaying notifications is done by the launcher. Like any other app launchers can contain bugs. In this case there is a bug in the launcher you're using to display multiple actions in a notification.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to try a google sample Universal Music player Here is a [GitHub link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) . It includes all of you want in notifications and it has a latest notification Android Oreo features just try out it .